# Why it's not possible to trigger an event from callback in Kivy

Tags: python, triggers, callback, kivy

**Hi everyone!**

I ran into a problem with ***Kivy + events & callbacks***.

When I try to run a callback from another callback - it fails.

The firs callback `on_spinner1_select` should trigger with a **ClockEvent** `self._myevent = Clock.create_trigger(...)` the second callback `_update_something`. The first callback is called properly, but the `_update_something` will never be called.
*What's the reason for that behaviour?*

Here is my simple example:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
import time


kv_app_layout = """
#<KvLang>
MyLayout:
    id: _mylayout
    spinner1: _spnr1
    label1: _lbl1
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 2
    spacing: 2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Line:
            width: .5
            rectangle: (self.x+1, self.y-1, self.width-2, self.height-1)
    Spinner:
        id: _spnr1
        text:  'Some Text'
        values:   ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        size_hint:  1, .5
        on_text:  root.on_spinner1_select(self.text)

    Label:
        id: _lbl1
        size_hint:  1, .5
#</KvLang>
"""


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):
    
    spinner1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    label1 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._myevent = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self._update_something)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_spinner1_select(self, text):
        self._myevent()

    def _update_something(self):
        print(f"Called: {time.asctime()}")
        self.label1.text = f"{self.spinner1.text} called on {time.asctime()}"

class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv_app_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()
```

I'm on:

- python 3.7 x64
- kivy 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the `_update_something` called by slightly twisting your code

[Here's the result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBB3h.png)

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
import time


kv_app_layout = """
#<KvLang>
MyLayout:
    id: _mylayout
    spinner1: _spnr1
    label1: _lbl1
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 2
    spacing: 2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Line:
            width: .5
            rectangle: (self.x+1, self.y-1, self.width-2, self.height-1)
    Spinner:
        id: _spnr1
        text:  'Some Text'
        values:   ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        size_hint:  1, .5
        on_text:  root.on_spinner1_select(self.text)

    Label:
        id: _lbl1
        size_hint:  1, .5
#</KvLang>
"""


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    spinner1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    label1 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._myevent = Clock.create_trigger(self._update_something)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_spinner1_select(self, text):
        self._myevent()

    def _update_something(self,dt):
        print(f"Called: {time.asctime()}")
        self.label1.text = f"{self.spinner1.text} called on {time.asctime()}"

class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv_app_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleApp().run()
```

Make sure to follow the format stated in the [Kivy Documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html)

Using lambda function should work also but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't explain why it's not working with `lambda`, as it is also explained in Kivy docs.